# Generate an N-dimensional matrix using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, random, probability

For a certain assignment, I have to create a multivariate discrete probability mass function over `N` random variables. I want to do this by creating an array `A` filled with random numbers where each element denotes the joint probability over the random variables. In case of 2 random variables, having `i` and `j` possible values respectively, this can be done by creating an `(i*j)` Numpy array filled with random numbers where the total sum = 1.

It becomes more difficult however, when an additional random variable with `k` possible values is introduced. In this case, I need to have an `i*j*k` Numpy array, again filled with random numbers where the total sum equals 1.

Say I am given the structure (number of possible values for each random variable) as a list `[n1,n2,...,nN]`, how can I from here create such an `N` dimensional Numpy array?

Comment: What did you do? Show us the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `l` is your list of dimensions, you could let

```
a = np.random.random(size=l)
a = a/a.sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the following solution:

```
def randomArray(structure):
    rand_array = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(structure))
    my_sum = np.sum(rand_array)
    return rand_array/my_sum
```

where `structure` is a list as defined in the question above.